# How do I install and keep updated with the most recent versions of Blender on Ubuntu?

Tags: blender

[Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29) is a perfect piece of software with many brilliant changes in each minor release. But often the most recent versions of Ubuntu does not have the latest versions of Blender.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you add [this blender ppa](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender) as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
```

Followed by `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install blender`

From now on, any updates to the ppa should be offered automatically.

Comment: This ppa is no longer maintained. Is there another way to install the latest version

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple way of having the latest version of Blender in your Ubuntu distribution:

1. Visit http://www.blender.org/, find the appropriate version of the latest Blender package (64-bit or 32-bit for Linux) in the download section, and save it somewhere on your filesystem.
2. I assume that it's not a problem for you to have two additional items in your home directory.

   ```
   cd ~
   tar -xvjf Downloads/blender-2.65a-linux-glibc211-x86_64.tar.bz2
   ln -s blender-2.65a-linux-glibc211-x86_64 blender
   ```
3. Add an item to the menu:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
   ```

   Then edit with your favorite editor `~/.local/share/applications/blender.desktop` and save it with the following content:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Blender
   Comment=3d design/modelling suite
   Icon=/home/USER/blender/icons/32x32/apps/blender.png
   Exec=/home/USER/blender/blender
   Categories=Graphics
   ```

   Don't forget to change `/home/USER/` with your home directory.
4. When a new version of Blender will be released all you have to do is to download it, extract and renew the symlink `~/blender` to point to the new version of Blender:

   ```
   rm ~/blender
   ln -s ~/blender-most-recent-version ~/blender
   ```

Comment: How do I make .blend files be associated with Blender when installing via this method?