# Binary file wont run. How do I install it?

Tags: system-installation, blender

I downloaded the 2.70 release of blender from the blender website (blender.org) and extracted the file to /home. The instructions in the readme say that I need to simply run the executable binary. However when I attempt to open the file nothing happens. I opened a bash and made the file executable, still no dice.

what am I doing wrong here? the terminal just tells me that it cannot execute the binary file...

I do not want the build available from the software center as it is v2.62. I already have this installed and am trying to install the 2.7 build available from the website

Output from the console

```
cromwell@Terminal:~$ sudo chmod +x /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender
[sudo] password for cromwell: 
cromwell@Terminal:~$ sudo /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender
/home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender: 2: /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
cromwell@Terminal:~$
```

---

```
cromwell@Terminal:/$ ls /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64
2.70                    GPL3-license.txt       LICENSE-bmonofont-i18n.ttf.txt
blender                 GPL-license.txt        LICENSE-droidsans.ttf.txt
blenderplayer           icons                  Python-license.txt
blender-softwaregl      jemalloc-license.txt   readme.html
blender-thumbnailer.py  lib
copyright.txt           LICENSE-bfont.ttf.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't corrupted? If possible, try re-downloading the file using a better tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/s/wget/‎)

Comment: the file was downloaded from a web page... see my answer... i got it working... i believe it may have something to do with missing dependencies

Comment: great because, there is also a binary copy from the repository if we are still talking about blender..

Comment: @OluDoug the repo had the v2.63 build which doesn’t include cycles or volumetric rendering, where as the website had the new 2.70 release.

Comment: Cool. Okay then, that's good.

Comment: What does `head -n 1 /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason (Hopefully someone will be kind enough to explain) the following post helped me to fix my problem and i am now running blender 2.70 =)

it was the first post that did it for me

[How do I install and keep updated with the most recent versions of Blender on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253448/how-to-install-and-keep-updated-most-recent-versions-of-blender-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

First make the binary file executable,

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/the/binary/file
```

Then run the binary file,

```
sudo ./binary-file-name           # Before running this command, you have to cding into the directory where the binary file is placed.
```

Comment: didnt work... see the console in the OP

Comment: `cd /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64` and then `sudo ./blender`

Comment: still complaining about an exterminated quoted string

Comment: post the output of `ls /home/cromwell/blender-2.70-linux-glibc211-x86_64` command.