# Blender 2.70 not installed, but can open it, yet can't find it in dash or add it to launcher

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, directory, blender

I have downloaded [Blender 2.7](http://www.blender.org/) and moved it to folder `/opt` and yet I can't find it in dash or place it in launcher. I have searched for solutions on the net, but I don't quite understand those.

Comment: I'd say that Blender is not really a command-line application

Comment: You may also want to read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253448/how-to-install-and-keep-updated-most-recent-versions-of-blender-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you absolutely need features or bug fixes only present in Blender 2.70 I'd use the version available in the Ubuntu repositories ([2.69](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/blender) for 14.04).

You can easily install it from the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Properly packaged for Ubuntu, Blender comes with a `.desktop` file (see the package [list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/blender/filelist)) allowing the dash to find it (and can also be used as a launcher icon).

**UPDATE**:

I assume that you installed blender in `/opt/blender-2.70a-linux-glibc211-x86_64`.

So the only thing missing to enable dash search and a launcher icon is a `.desktop` file like this one:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.70a
Name=Blender
GenericName=3D modeller
GenericName[es]=modelador 3D
GenericName[de]=3D-Modellierer
GenericName[fr]=modeleur 3D
GenericName[ru]=Редактор 3D-моделей
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Comment[es]=modelado 3D, animación, renderizado y post-producción
Comment[de]=3D-Modellierung, Animation, Rendering und Nachbearbeitung
Exec=/opt/blender-2.70a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender
Icon=/opt/blender-2.70a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/icons/256x256/apps/blender.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```

After you've created this `blender.desktop` file, just drag and drop it somewhere onto your launcher.

Note: You may have to change the path to the blender exe/icon if you downloaded the `i386` tar.bz2.

Comment: I really want the latest version

Comment: Excellent it worked But blender doesn't appear in dash.

Comment: it worked for me, i used the following Blender.desktop - [Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
Comment=To place in /usr/share/applications/ or $HOME/.local/share/applications/
Exec=/home/vikrant/Documents/softwares/multimedia/blender/install/blender %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Icon=/home/vikrant/Documents/softwares/multimedia/blender/install/icons/scalable/apps/blender.svg
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=Blender
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;