# Problems on adding Actions in .desktop file

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I am working on Blender recently, but the problem turns up when I set up the desktop icon file. Sometimes I need Blender to open with a terminal, but most time is "no it is not useful". Although I can open a terminal and type `blender` to do so, but it is not convince, I think. What I want is a desktop/launcher icon with a "Open with terminal" item.
I find a tutorial on help.ubuntu, and here is my desktop file(an action is added):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
GenericName=3D modeler
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Keywords=3d;cg;modeling;animation;painting;sculpting;texturing;video editing;video tracking;rendering;render engine;cycles;game engine;python;
Exec=blender %f
Icon=blender
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
Name[en_US]=Blender

Actions=with_terminal

[Desktop Action with_terminal]
Name=Open-With-terminal
Exec=blender %f
Terminal=true
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

But actually, when I click on the right click list, the program start but no terminal was opened.
For a detail description, here are my pictures(Sorry I cannot show a picture, but superlinks in my question for less reputations). 
[image]

Also, I want a customized icon not only in my launcher but on my desktop as well.
[image]

In short, there are two problems:

1. Why the terminal not turn up from the right click action?
2. Can I customize the right click item on my desktop?

Comment: @MohamedSlama the terminal turns up if Terminal set to true, but do you read my requirement? I do not want the terminal if I click the main button. Also the extra right click list don't have my customized item if these lines are commented.

Comment: check this answer how to create **blender** `.desktop` file http://askubuntu.com/a/455266/464430

Comment: @MohamedSlama sorry, I may don't catch your idea properly, do you mean I should change exec on line 8? So where will be my add on action?

Comment: @MohamedSlama yeah, but I installed blender with adding a PPA, in order to update convinced. So my blender may not in /opt , and I can run blender in terminal without cd to the directory. also, I am not asking how to create the desktop file, but to customize it with a Open-with -terminal item.

Comment: @Mohamed Slama er...we may have misunderstanding  between us, I sorry to my poor English, but please wait for a while to explain what I need on earth, hope not bother you lot.

Comment: Hi David, posted my answer. Please mention if you manage.

Comment: @MohamedSlama So let me tell my story. I found I can develop game in blender with Python programs, I am fond of Python as well you know. But I found if I want to debug the python file, the terminal is needed(or the error info would not show ) , so every time I need to open the terminal and type blender, and the blender will be launched with a terminal behind it. But some time, I would try model some small objects, so my game would not be too ugly. Then, you will find if I need the terminal , the shortcut on desktop would not be used, so I need a extra item in right click list.

Comment: @DavidPage you can check this answer or "Jacob Vlijm" answer may solving your problem http://askubuntu.com/a/34598/464430

Comment: @MohamedSlama yeah this is what I need, thank you. ...oh, he is just below my question, HAHAHA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are actually two questions, but here we go:

1. In a `.desktop` file, usually, combining `Terminal=false` and `Terminal=true` is not working out well. Most of the time, only one works well, the one in the "main" command.  Alternatively, set for the command:

   ```
   Exec=gnome-terminal -e <command>
   ```

   In this case:

   ```
   Exec=gnome-terminal -e blender
   ```
2. For your second issue, adding right-click option to the icon on your desktop: I do not have a `Blender`- specific solution, but you can create a small script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gnome-terminal -e blender
   ```

   Save it as `Blender_wterminal` (no extension) in

   ```
   ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
   ```

   Create the directory if it does not exist yet. ***Make the script executable***. Subsequently, you might have to log out/in.

   Then, on right- click on *any* icon on your desktop, choose <kbd>scripts</kbd> > <kbd>Blender_wterminal</kbd> will open `Blender` in the terminal.

   [image]

Comment: So in the second answer, I should click on the icon or on the plain area on desktop?

Comment: @DavidPage right-click *on* the icon on your desktop, as in your second image. You might have to log out/in before it works.

Comment: hope I can use actions in desktop file on my desktop in unity 8;)

Comment: @DavidPage would be nice!

Comment: do you know the URL of Ubuntu desktop team? I want issue this suggestion to them, but I googled a lot but failed to find how to communicate with them.