# Cannot see anything in the viewport

Tags: blender

Whenever I open blender I cannot see anything in the viewport: no grid, no objects, nothing. It was suggested that it might be a hardware issue, if so how do I fix it?

This is what I see:

[image: viewport]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot so that we can see what you see? Please help us help you.

Comment: no I need 10 reps before I can post a picture

Comment: upload it to imgur.com and post the link. Thank you!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/woPFGC4.png

Comment: What do you expect to see that you aren't seeing?

Comment: I am expecting to see the Grid and objects, I have not made any changes to the settings. I simply installed it and opened it and this is what I saw

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what is causing this glitch, but you should try the latest version of Blender instead of the outdated version in Ubuntu’s repositories.

Download it from the [Official Blender website](http://www.blender.org/download/).

Maybe this is a bug related to the version of Blender, not to your system; in this case, using a more recent version should fix it.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/253448/183698) has more info on getting up to date versions. 2.62 is about 2.5 years old.

Comment: I am using the updated version as well, I tried the old version when I was getting the same problem with new  2.71 version.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/z5VIsYC.png?1

Comment: Sorry I can't help you then. You should try asking this question also in http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the View menu, there is an option called View Properties, which has a button to turn the grid on or off.

source (and further commentary on this topic) http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?118080-grid-visibility

If that fails, look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8303/grid-floor-disappears-and-cannot-see-outline-of-selected-objects

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this option already and again but I am still not seeing anything..